# How to add a non-authoritative DNS entry?

Tags: dns

So I was doing `whois microsoft.com` and this was the output:

`MICROSOFT.COM.ARE.GODDAMN.PIGFUCKERS.NET.NS-NOT-IN-SERVICE.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.CAN.GO.FUCK.ITSELF.AT.SECZY.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.EENGURRA.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.FILLS.ME.WITH.BELLIGERENCE.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.HAS.A.PRESENT.COMING.FROM.HUGHESMISSILES.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.A.MESS.TIMPORTER.CO.UK
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.A.STEAMING.HEAP.OF.FUCKING-BULLSHIT.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.HOSTED.ON.PROFITHOSTING.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.IN.BED.WITH.CURTYV.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.YEPPA.ORG
MICROSOFT.COM.LIVES.AT.SHAUNEWING.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.LOVES.ME.KOSMAL.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.MAKES.RICKARD.DRINK.SAMBUCA.0800CARRENTAL.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.MATCHES.THIS.STRING.AT.KEYSIGNERS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.MORE.INFO.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.RAWKZ.MUH.WERLD.MENTALFLOSS.CA
MICROSOFT.COM.SHOULD.GIVE.UP.BECAUSE.LINUXISGOD.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.SOFTWARE.IS.NOT.USED.AT.REG.RU
MICROSOFT.COM.WAREZ.AT.TOPLIST.GULLI.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.BEATEN.WITH.MY.SPANNER.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.SLAPPED.IN.THE.FACE.BY.MY.BLUE.VEINED.SPANNER.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZ.IS.0WNED.AND.HAX0RED.BY.SUB7.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZ.MORE.DETAILS.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.IM.ELITE.WANNABE.TOO.WWW.PLUS613.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.IS.A.GREAT.COMPANY.ITREBAL.COM
MICROSOFT.COM`

I thought they were hacked but that's unlikely for such a big company, so I thought that these are non-authorative DNS entries.

- Is that correct? If not, what is it then?
- If so, how do I do this?
- And can this be prevented with DNSSEC?

PS. There are multiple domains with this issue...

`whois google.com`

`GOOGLE.COM.AFRICANBATS.ORG
GOOGLE.COM.AR
GOOGLE.COM.AU
GOOGLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
GOOGLE.COM.BR
GOOGLE.COM.CN
GOOGLE.COM.CO
GOOGLE.COM.DO
GOOGLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES
GOOGLE.COM.HANNAHJESSICA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HAS.LESS.FREE.PORN.IN.ITS.SEARCH.ENGINE.THAN.SECZY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HK
GOOGLE.COM.IS.APPROVED.BY.NUMEA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.IS.HOSTED.ON.PROFITHOSTING.NET
GOOGLE.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
GOOGLE.COM.LASERPIPE.COM
GOOGLE.COM.LOLOLOLOLOL.SHTHEAD.COM
GOOGLE.COM.MX
GOOGLE.COM.MY
GOOGLE.COM.NS1.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.NS2.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.PE
GOOGLE.COM.PK
GOOGLE.COM.RAINGUTTERPRO.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SA
GOOGLE.COM.SHQIPERIA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SOUTHBEACHNEEDLEARTISTRY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPROSIUYANDEKSA.RU
GOOGLE.COM.SUCKS.FIND.CRACKZ.WITH.SEARCH.GULLI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.TR
GOOGLE.COM.TW
GOOGLE.COM.UA
GOOGLE.COM.UY
GOOGLE.COM.VABDAYOFF.COM
GOOGLE.COM.VN
GOOGLE.COM.WORDT.DOOR.VEEL.WHTERS.GEBRUIKT.SERVERTJE.NET
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEKIRBAC.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZNAET.PRODOMEN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.HAVENDATA.COM
GOOGLE.COMMAS2CHAPTERS.COM
GOOGLE.COM`

`whois apple.com`

`APPLE.COM.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES
APPLE.COM.IS.0WN3D.BY.GULLI.COM
APPLE.COM.IS.OWN3D.BY.NAKEDJER.COM
APPLE.COM.MORE.INFO.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.WAS.PWNED.BY.M1CROSOFT.COM
APPLE.COM.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.WWW.ZON.COM
APPLE.COM.ZON.COM
APPLE.COM`

Comment: Where did you run this whois command, was this on a local computer of yours, or what?

Comment: For the record, an non-authoritative DNS response just simply means that the nameserver answering the query is not the nameserver of record for the domain.  It's a pretty normal thing and unrelated to the problem you have which I suspect is malware related I but have no idea which direction for you to follow.

Comment: @Zoredache Yes.

Comment: @Tyson I don't have a problem (malware). Try a Google search for `whois microsoft hacked` (even though it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

The WHOIS command you're using isn't working correctly. Valid WHOIS data would look something like this:

```
Domain Name: MICROSOFT.COM
Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Referral URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Name Server: NS1.MSFT.NET
Name Server: NS2.MSFT.NET
Name Server: NS3.MSFT.NET
Name Server: NS4.MSFT.NET
Name Server: NS5.MSFT.NET
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Status: serverDeleteProhibited
Status: serverTransferProhibited
Status: serverUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 09-aug-2011
Creation Date: 02-may-1991
Expiration Date: 03-may-2021

>>> Last update of whois database: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 21:25:44 UTC <<<
```

In fact, it looks like the data you're getting is nothing more than a list of **DNS hostnames** that *contain* the search term you are using.  Take for example, the third result in your *microsoft.com* query:

```
 MICROSOFT.COM.EENGURRA.COM
```

DNS hostnames are interpreted from *right to left*. That means in this case the domain name is **EENGURRA.COM**.  Whoever controls eengurra.com can create whatever subdomains and hostnames in their domain that they want. These are added to the **left** of their domain name.

In this case, eengurra.com created the subdomain **com** and in that subdomain they created a hostname **microsoft**. The result is the hostname *microsoft* in the domain *com.eengurra.com*. Put them together and you get *microsoft.com.eengurra.com*, which, despite appearing associated with microsoft.com, is nothing more than a deceiving manipulation of DNS entries all within the domain controlled by the owner of eengurra.com.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am using the standard WHOIS tool in Mac OS X by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The whois systems is only tangentially related to DNS.  It does not use the DNS protocol, it is not required for the DNS protocol to work.  It is is a completely separate database and [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois#Protocol).  Your whois client is almost certainly pointing to a whois server with invalid data, or somehow your request is being redirected to a bad whois server.  There are several different whois

DNSSEC wouldn't help anything, since this isn't whois isn't DNS.

I would take the time to try and isolate how your whois requests are being subverted.  Some kind of malware could have updated the configuration for your whois client pointing you at invalid whois server, or perhaps malware as completely replaced the whois binary.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/797601/how-to-add-a-non-authoritative-dns-entry?noredirect=1#comment1041685_797601

Answer (score -2):

-whois doesn't only list domain names, it also lists name server records.

People probably created name server records for their domains with those messages in the host name of their name servers. These are probably not real hosts, but they do appear in the queries queries.